# how to get value of attribute href value in Go language

Tags: go, goquery

I want to parse anchor link from the html content.
/* My HTML Content Sample

```
<a class="productnamecolor colors_productname" href="http://www.cccxcxc.com/Nautical-Bubble-Romper-p/s15brpnt03.htm">*/
      <a class="productnamecolor colors_productname" href="http://www.dewewe.com/Nautical-Bubble-Romper-p/erewrwer.htm">
    <a class="productnamecolor colors_productname" href="http://www.sdsddsd.com/Nautical-Bubble-Romper-p/dsadadasd.htm">
```

*/
The Anchor have **href** and i want to get the value of **Href** . But this is giving me error..

**Error: multiple-value s.Attr() in single-value context**

```
package main

    import (
      "fmt"
      "log"

      "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
    )

    func ExampleScrape() {
      doc, err := goquery.NewDocument("http://www.myurl.com/category-s/1828.htm") 
      if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
      }

    /* **my sample html after http open** <a class="productnamecolor colors_productname" href="http://www.cccxcxc.com/Nautical-Bubble-Romper-p/s15brpnt03.htm">*/
      <a class="productnamecolor colors_productname" href="http://www.dewewe.com/Nautical-Bubble-Romper-p/erewrwer.htm">
    <a class="productnamecolor colors_productname" href="http://www.sdsddsd.com/Nautical-Bubble-Romper-p/dsadadasd.htm"> ***/

    doc.Find("table.v65-productDisplay a.productnamecolor").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
        band := s.Attr("href") // here i want to get attribute " href " value. this is not working here.
        fmt.Printf(band)
      })
    }

    func main() {
      ExampleScrape()
    }
```

Comment: You should clearly ask your question in sentences and paragraphs rather than relying on the title and comments in a code block.

Comment: Is [the `golang.org/x/net/html` package](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html/) relevant/helpful?

Comment: @DaveC i have also tried with this package but problem is this it does not gives the css selectors..

Comment: @PuzzledBoy What do you mean by that? You can every attribute/tag with that package just fine. You just don't get the syntax of `doc.Find("tag.classattr")` although writing your own function do that is actually really easy once you get familiar with that package.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`Selection.Attr`](https://godoc.org/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#Selection.Attr) returns two values: the attribute value, and a boolean stating whether the attribute existed or not (the attribute value will be the empty if this is false).

Go doesn't like it when you ignore multiple return values, so you'll have to change your code to the following:

```
doc.Find("table.v65-productDisplay a.productnamecolor").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
    band, ok := s.Attr("href")
    if ok {
        fmt.Printf(band)
    }
})
```

Comment: ahh i was just reading https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery/issues/46 .. Thanx Sir,

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [golang.org/pkg/net/html](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/html?tab=doc#example-Parse) package.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strings"

    "golang.org/x/net/html"
)

func main() {
    s := `<a class="productnamecolor colors_productname" href="http://www.cccxcxc.com/Nautical-Bubble-Romper-p/s15brpnt03.htm">*/
      <a class="productnamecolor colors_productname" href="http://www.dewewe.com/Nautical-Bubble-Romper-p/erewrwer.htm">
    <a class="productnamecolor colors_productname" href="http://www.sdsddsd.com/Nautical-Bubble-Romper-p/dsadadasd.htm">`
    doc, err := html.Parse(strings.NewReader(s))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    var f func(*html.Node)
    f = func(n *html.Node) {
        if n.Type == html.ElementNode && n.Data == "a" {
            for _, a := range n.Attr {
                if a.Key == "href" {
                    fmt.Println(a.Val)
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        for c := n.FirstChild; c != nil; c = c.NextSibling {
            f(c)
        }
    }
    f(doc)
}
// outputs
// http://www.cccxcxc.com/Nautical-Bubble-Romper-p/s15brpnt03.htm
// http://www.dewewe.com/Nautical-Bubble-Romper-p/erewrwer.htm
// http://www.sdsddsd.com/Nautical-Bubble-Romper-p/dsadadasd.htm
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thank you @Dami . It is an extremely elegant and lightweight solution

Comment: Happy to help! @wooknight